# get ERROR "Internal tables cannot be used as work areas" inside of method

Tags: sql, loops, abap

I am new with `ABAP`. I asked a similar, **but different**, question to this one yesterday.

I duplicate a table (`= table`) to a local table (`= localTable`) and remove all duplicates in it, this works fine (*first 3 code lines*)

Now I want to loop over this *local table* and send all matching data into an structure with `INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF` - unfortunately I always get the following error:

```
Internal tables cannot be used as work areas.
```

**INFO:** I'm working inside of a method!

Here is my code where I'm working with:

```
DATA localTable TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF table. 
SELECT columnName FROM table INTO TABLE localTable.
  DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM localTable COMPARING columnName.

LOOP AT localTable ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_table>).
  SELECT * FROM anotherTable as p
    WHERE p~CN1 = @localVariable
    AND p~CN2 = @<fs_table>-columnName
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF @exportStructure "<-- Here I always get my error
  ENDSELECT.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what the final goal is? You select multiple entries, but only have one export structure. Do you really want that? Or do you want to export a table? `SELECT` without `SINGLE` will return many rows, not just one. And looping to return one line seems weird.

Comment: Add the key word TABLE in front of @exportStructure and remove the ENDSELECT and I suspect you'd get what you want. The issue is that with a SELECT ENDSELECT you are creating a loop processing every entry in the database table one by one into a structure, with the addition of TABLE all the data will be extracted in one go and put into an internal table. Oops, too quick, you'd also need to add FOR ALL ENTRIES IN localtab to replace the LOOP.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help!! I've solved it for my own - as you can see in the answers! :)

Comment: In ABAP, the meaning of "structure" is the same as ["record" or structure as explained in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_%28computer_science%29), it doesn't mean a table of several lines. It's why the people here were confused. Next time, please answer their questions, otherwise they won't be motivated to help you. To avoid this kind of misunderstanding, please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which would have made it clear that `exportStructure` was in fact an "internal table".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First:* I've read that I have to sort my `internal table` before using command `DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM localTable COMPARING columnName.` so I've added following code line in between:

```
SORT localTable BY columnName ASCENDING.
```

*Second:* Instead of using *`INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE`* I've used **`APPENDING CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE`** because **INTO** overwrites every line with itself, so in total I have only one line in my exported structure.

**APPENDING** adds a new line every time my statements are true.

Comment: In ABAP and other languages, "structure" is completely different from "table", in your case you should use the word "table", and more specifically in ABAP the name is "internal table" which stands for a variable representing a table in memory, to distinguish from a "database table".

Comment: IMO, it is better to use `FOR ALL ENTRIES` using `LOCALTABLE` rather than looping over it. Also, an `INTO TABLE` on your select statement would remove your `ENDSELECT` loop.